# Convention swag for promotion?

Tags: discussion, top-7, convention, site-promotion

Often, when you go to a convention that supports gaming, they'll give you a grab-bag of **free convention swag** at registration. What *specific* item can we create to give away at a convention and promote the site?

Some ideas:

- Keychain
- Plastic dragon mini
- Button w/site logo
- Cheap collectible game
- Branded dice?

Example contents of a grab-bag from various Dexcons (www.dexposure.com):

- Battlestar Galactica Keychain
- Copy of Scientific American
- Toy insect (goes with an online webgame)
- Cheapass Games(TM) button game (you wear a button w/character picture and stats, and you can duel other people with buttons)

We need postcards, and business cards, but I think we have the potential with this site audience to come up with something unique and cool that people will really want to hang on to.

Answer (score 4):

Dice would be pretty cool. Something like a ? for the 1 and the logo for the 6, maybe? Here're some custom die costs; looks like it'd cost around $2.50 per die if the print run was in the thousands.

- [Crystal Caste](http://www.crystalcaste.com/custom.htm)
- [Chessex](http://www.chessex.com/Dice/Custom_Dice_Home.htm)
- [Game Station](http://customdice.com/pricing.php) (way cheaper, not sure why)
- [Q Workshop](http://q-workshop.com/help_more.php?topic=customdice&lang=EN&sell_type=DETAL&currency=EUR) (picky about design)

Comment: +1 for dice. Waiting to see if other people will vote on this =)